# Silent Refresh not working after Google Chrome updated to Version 85

Tags: refresh, openid-connect, silent, angular-oauth2-oidc, referrer-policy

I am using angular-oidc-auth2 v9.0.3 to request token renewal by silent refresh. I am using implicit flow.
it was working good until google chrome updated version to 85.
I have observed the request and found that Google chrome used to have
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade before
and all was good. then from version 85 they have defaulted to
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin.
and after that it started failing the token refresh.
For security reason I cannot share the code however our identity server is in the different domain than application.
Is there anyway I can set header for referrer policy Silent refresh request?
Or any other way it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default says that you need to only refer to your own site in a script.

You will need to write a proxy script in the form...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. could you please shade some light /example on the proxy things?

Comment: The best explanation I have found so far is this one.  https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution and its not Implicit flow. Required PKCE + Code flow and works perfectly. Implicit flow is dead bow or will be dead soon